# Change Google Translator Text

Tags: jquery, css, google-translator-toolkit

Can you change the text on the Google Translator to display Translator instead of select language?

https://jsfiddle.net/ogp8xobz/2/

I have tried:

```
$('#google_translate_element').text("Translator");
$('#google_translate_element span').text("Translator");
```

Comment: Your fiddle is missing jQuery. You can use it by clicking the cog wheel in the top right of the JS box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That element (#google_translate_element) has many child elements, the text you're looking for is inside a span inside an anchor inside a span inside a div inside a div inside #google_translate_element. To do this properly, you should address only that very last span:

```
  $($(" #google_translate_element .goog-te-menu-value span")[0]).html("this one?");
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/tgokbf5j/